# mongo export SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:14

Tags: mongodb, export, syntax-error

Hi i'm trying to export one of my mongo collection by using this comande line :

`mongoexport --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 --db meteor --collection subs --out subs.json`

but i get this error and i don't understand why because every post use this command and it works for them

`2017-11-14T10:23:31.562+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:14`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`mongoexport` must be run from your OS command shell, not in mongo shell.

Comment: Thanks, I tried many time same command but getting same error. Now Its working.